# Translate Password/E-mail confirmation fields error message for Experience Forms

Tags: sitecore-forms, multilingual

I've been using [these](https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2017/10/sitecore-9-forms-translating-error.html) [blogposts](https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2019/04/sitecore-9-forms-translating-client-error.html) to translate the error-messages that Sitecore Forms uses into Dutch and German for our client. But I can't seem to find any Sitecore item or dictionary-entry to translate the error messages that come with the "E-mail confirmation" and "Password confirmation" form field-types.

The only thing I can see (using JustDecompile) is that the message that currently pops up seems to be the hard-coded `ErrorMessage` param of the `LocalizedCompare` attribute in `Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Models.Fields.PasswordConfirmationViewModel` and `EmailConfirmationViewModel`:

```
[LocalizedCompare("Value", TitleProperty="ConfirmPasswordLabel", OtherTitleProperty="Title", ErrorMessage="The {0} and {1} do not match.")]
public string ConfirmPassword
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

How would I go about translating those? We're on Sitecore 9.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create  a dictionary item with the key: **The {0} and {1} do not match.**

[image]

You will see then the error message on the page :

[image]

I test in on 9.3 version.

Comment: Thanks! Too bad I can't have a different message for e-mail and password since Dictionary keys have to be unique.